# Why two variables with the same name don't clash in this case?

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I was reading typeahead.js [documentation](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) and found this code:

```
var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska'];
//... more code
var states = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
    local: $.map(states, function(state) { return { value: state }; })
});
```

What I cannot understand is why `Bloodhound` object uses `states` array and it does not clash with the latter declaration of `states` variable?

I know it [shouldn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433560/1189456) unless it's [nested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7516215/1189456). But is doesn't seem to be the case.

I did my own experiment:

```
var a = 3;
var a = function(){ alert(a + 2); }
a();
```

Output: `function(){ alert(a + 2); }2` which proves that it's shouldn't work.

Is this one of those javascript peculiarities?

Comment: The first `states` will be overwritten since they're in the same scope.

Comment: I don't see the variable used twice in the same code anywhere on that page. Note that both of those instances are in different examples.

Comment: @Juhana here http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/js/examples.js lines 30 to 61

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the variable a after it is initialized as a function.
If you experiment with something like,

```
var a = 10;
var a = {b: a+10}
```

You will see that a is,

```
{b: 20}
```

The states array is accessed before it is overridden.

Comment: this answer with your comment to Chuck's answer explain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is reassigned when that statement finishes executing. In that statement, the variable still has its old value. This is similar to `a = a +1`.

Comment: that's what I thought. But in that case, why in my example the `a` in the `alert` is not 3?

Comment: var a = function(){ alert(a + 2); }
In the above statement, function is only declared. Not invoked. In the next like when you are invoking the function with statement a(), this time a is already a function